# how to set up splunk stand alone environment

Tags: admin, splunk, splunk-query

As I want to create stand-alone where heavyforwarder,indexer,search head in single server.
mostly stand-alone used for staging environment, I want to use stand alone for testing few apps.
How to set-up stand-alone for splunk?

Comment: You need to share what you have tried so far .

Answer (score 1):

The Splunk has two major products :-

1. Splunk Enterprise
2. Splunk Universal Forwarder

List item

1. Splunk Enterprise - In Splunk Enterprise has Heavy Forwarder, Indexer, Search Head, Deployer , Deployment Server, Cluster Master, License Master as their components.
2. Splunk Universal Forwarder - It has only Splunk Universal Forwarder.

As Stated in the question, for having these three Splunk Component that is heavyforwarder,indexer,search head in single server, you need to install **Splunk Enterprise**

You can install Splunk Enterprise from the below link:-

[Splunk Enterprise Installation link](https://www.splunk.com/en_us/download/splunk-enterprise.html)

Answer (score 0):

A standalone Splunk system is a combined search head and indexer - no forwarders.  Installing a forwarder on a Splunk system is redundant.

That said, the installation is very simple.  Download the installer and run it.

Comment: Thanks for response, installation which means installing splunk enterprise in windows system right??

Comment: Right.  For Windows, download and run the .msi file and follow the prompts.